# PHPUnit pass configuration file and test file path

Tags: phpunit

I want to keep as much of my configuration stored in a configuration file as possible. There are times when I want to only run the tests in a specific file in addition to using my normal configuration options. Is there a way to pass both a configuration file and a single test filepath for PHPUnit to run?

Comment: Will [test selection options](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html) solve your problem?

Comment: @BVengerov No. The test file will not be the only one in a suite or group. The --filter option almost works right, but you can't specify a path. I got it to partially work by passing the filename (not the path) without the file extension to --filter, but that is not always accurate enough.

Comment: I guess I could parse the config file, remove the options that don't apply, and then generate terminal options with the applicable options in addition to specifying a path to run. But it would seem strange if that is the lengths I have to go. I would think a lot of developers already do this somehow. Sigh.. I guess they all just use PhpStorm...

Comment: Ugh, maybe I will try SimpleTest again. I actually really liked SimpleTest in the past and only started using PHPUnit recently because it was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use testsuites?

Example:

Config file:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Example">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">src/tests</directory>
        <file>tests/WhateverTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Command line:

```
phpunit --testsuite Example
```

?

Comment: This does not work for me because the file name has to be manually added / changed in the configuration file every time I want to test a different file. The whole point is I switch to having different files open in my editor, and I want to want to run just the file I am looking at. I can create my own shortcuts that will generate and run terminal commands based on which file I have open. I guess I could generate the xml file on the fly as well, but that seems like more work than it should be. Anyway, I have already converted all my test code over to SimpleTest now and that is working well.

Comment: sort of related and maybe more helpful to others - Visual Studio Code editor has a phpunit plugin which is brilliant for that. whatever file you have open, run Ctrl+Shift+P and it will run the unit test on the file you have open. saves loads of time!

Comment: Sort of related, but I would totally switch to VS Code if someone makes a Neovim plugin for it. By which I mean Neovim was designed to be embeddable. So the plugin would basically use VS Code as the UI for Neovim. So you would have a real Vim inside your IDE, not just a Vim emulator. I will try to make this eventually if nobody else does.

Comment: Also, even if you can just run a single file that way, that is only half of what I am asking for, I can already do that. I want to combine having a configuration file with only running the tests in a single test file. So the config file would contain settings that don't change or that you change manually when you want. But then only the tests in a single file run while also honoring the settings in the config file, for example the bootstrap setting.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are actually looking for.. ? running a single test file with a configuration file is done with --filter and -c for the config file, unless the same directory you run the phpunit from contains a phpunit.xml. The filter option can test a single class, a single method, a group of classes. I'm failing to see how that doesn't work for you. How are your test classes organised, and what is in your config file?